# How do I retrieve toast notification message in Xamarin UWP app?

Tags: azure, xamarin, notifications, uwp, toast

I am working with Xamarin UWP along with Azure notification hub to send Push notifications. I have the toast notifications showing up just fine, but when I click on the toast I need to be able to view the message. I can get a message to show up from the OnLaunched method when the notification is touched, with something like this:

```
     string text = string.Format("Launched with parameter: " + args.ToString());
     MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(text);
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

I can't figure out how to retrieve the message that was sent from the toast notification.

Comment: The activation samples from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts#Activation_samples) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have a background tasks that handles showing the the toast and I have break points in the Run() method but it doesn't ever get hit. Likewise the OnActivated() method. Am I sending the notification in such a way that would prevent these methods from being called?

Comment: ok it is getting into the OnActivated() method when i provide parameters through the launch property of the Toast

Comment: I still don't see how to access the text field directly to put that in a popup after the app is activated

Comment: If you set the text also in the launch parameter, you can receive it in OnActivated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting my text in the launch parameter to receive it in OnActivated